# Set Static IP Reservations on AirPort Extreme

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I am new to this, but I set up a little server for something up on a laptop connected to the Ethernet of the airport express. I had the server down for a few months and when I plugged it back in, I noticed that the local IP address had changed, and I had to change the IP on the port forwarding settings. Is there a way I can "force" this to be static so I don't have to change it every time the Local IP decides to change?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

According to the fourth hit on Google [here](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how_to_configure_a_static_dhcp_reservation_with_airport_extreme), all you need to do is open get the MAC address of your server, then open AirPort Utility and select your AirPort base station and choose edit (or just click on it if you're not using version 6.0+) and choose the Network tab. Seeing as how you have different local addresses, I'm assuming you have DHCP enabled (it's always a good idea) you just need to set up an IP reservation for the MAC address of your server.